# MongoDB doesn't increment numbers

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, integer, increment

i need to increment a number in MongoBD.
I'm using this code:

```
        let users = mongoose.db("wumpusCave").collection("users")

        console.log(data)
        let user = await users.findOne({"token": data.user})
        let bots = mongoose.db("wumpusCave").collection("bots")
        let bot = await bots.findOne({"id":data.bot})


        if(user != null && user.likedBots != null && bot != null) {
            users.findOneAndUpdate({"token": data.user}, {$push: {"likedBots": data.id}})
            console.log("bot a cui hai lasciato like aggiunto!!")
            bots.findOneAndUpdate(await {"id":data.bot}, {$inc: {"like": +1}})
            console.log("like aggiunto!")          
        }
    })
```

The push function works, but the increment function no.
It's doesn't give any error.

This is the database entry:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "60b62e0679182f0004714aac"
    },
    "id": "723877094920290305",
    "name": "rockpaperscissors",
    "description": "Gioca a sasso carta e forbici son i tuoi amici!",
    "invite": "https://discord.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=723877094920290305&scope=bot&permissions=67374144",
    "support_server": "",
    "developer": "465905397874688000",
    "avatar": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/app-icons/723877094920290305/2a580399fd50daa5b2c08b56de089c8e.png?size=256",
    "other_developers": "",
    "like": 0,
    "dislike": 0
}
```

I need to update "like" entry from the "id" value.
How i can do?
Thanks in advice and sorry for bad english!

Comment: I think it is because the await in this line: 
`bots.findOneAndUpdate(await {"id":data.bot}, {$inc: {"like": -1}})`
get rid of it, and try
 `await bots.findOneAndUpdate( {"id":data.bot}, {$inc: {"like": -1}})` instead

Comment: @HamzaBoukhtam it isn't works

Comment: ah! I just noticed id field is supposed to be _id not id
try it out `await bots.findOneAndUpdate( {"_id":data.bot}, {$inc: {"like": -1}})`

Comment: @BlackdestinyXX we need the entry or schema in your database you are trying to update, you just showed us the code, and without knowing what types/properties the object has is guesswork at this point.

Comment: @PHPNoob Now i've included the database entry, sorry

Comment: @BlackdestinyXX Since id is a string type, and $inc only works with numbers, you have a typing mismatch. Cast your id field into a int and then try it again with $inc (You can cast in mongo 4.0 using $toInt: "$value") https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toInt/

Comment: @PHPNoob i've fixed the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure you should not be quoting your property names for the object

```
if(user != null && user.likedBots != null && bot != null) {
    users.findOneAndUpdate({token: data.user}, {$push: {likedBots: data.id}})
    console.log("bot a cui hai lasciato like aggiunto!!")
    bots.findOneAndUpdate(await {id:data.bot}, {$inc: {like: -1}})
    console.log("like aggiunto!")          
}
```

})

Comment: can we see the entry already stored in your DB that you are trying to update?